# Using memory address as input

Tags: matlab, pointers, imread

I have a bunch of images in memory. I want to use the address of these images as input, so I can load them into matlab. I know I can use imread if I am not using memory address as input.

How can I do this?

Comment: Where do you get memory addresses from? How did you load the images into memory?

Comment: Someone else is using C programming to get memory address for me. I am supposed to use this memory address to retrieve images from the memory and load them into matlab.

Comment: Ok, I suggest you first learn how to load images (in general) into matlab. Then learn the special case of images from memory address.

Comment: I know how to use imread() to load images in

Comment: See https://www.google.com/search?q=reading+an+image+from+a+memory+address+in+matlab

Comment: MATLAB essentially runs in a localized JVM, so it's impossible to access these images from MATLAB using memory locations.  The only thing I can suggest is if you write another C program to extract out the data, perhaps save these raw bytes to file, then reconstruct them in MATLAB.

Comment: @rayryeng to work against the really bad unanswered question quote in this tag, you should post that as answer ;)

Comment: @thewaywewalk - lol funny.  I'm not sure if I should because it doesn't really help the OP.

Comment: @rayryeng - but in my opinion it is a valid question which should not be closed. And if your answer is, that there is no solution - then this is an answer worth posting. Especially because you are one of the top 5 image-processing dudes on SO.

Comment: @thewaywalk good point! Let me do a bit of research before posting. I'd like to have some proof to back myself up. For the benefit of everyone here on SO too.

Comment: How is this C-Application supposed to write the images into the memory? If it simply uses it's own address range everyone else accessing these addresses get's a segmentation fault.